# Can't include child document in subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats, incompatibility, include, subfiles

I'd like to save the PSTicks code for my images in seperate files and then include them with `\include{image.tex}`. This works fine with normal figure floats. But when I use subfloats, I get the error:

```
(./newfile1.aux (./file.tex.aux))
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.11    }
```

This minimal example works fine (file.tex can be also empty), but throws an error when the comment marks are removed:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

    %\subfloat[]{
        \include{file.tex}
    %}

    \caption{Caption}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The minimal example works as expected also if the include command is replaced by the content of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\include` is the wrong command for sure. It's meant for parts of the document structure like chapters which get their own `.aux` files.

Try `\input`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved everything. I didn't think about that, because it was working with out subfloats and I was using `\include` a lot before, but it was wrong everywhere...